# Gatsby plugin ERROR "UNHANDLED REJECTION Reducers may not dispatch actions."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, graphql-js

I have a problem with the initialization of Gatsby plugins, in gatsby.config.js. When I use a simple plugin in "string" in the plugin array there is no problem, but when I use a plugin with options in an object it doesn't work anymore.

```html
   
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    author: 'Me',
  },
  plugings: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`, 
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
               
      },
    },
  ]
};
```

When I use "npm run develop" I get this error message: 
"UNHANDLED REJECTION Reducers may not dispatch actions."

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turned out i hadn't specified the SITE_URL variable in my gatsby.config file, setting it to localhost:8888 fixed the problem, you are definetly missing this variable in siteMetadata consider adding it.